# Realistic 3D fractal Christmas tree

Tags: fractals, art

I would be interested to see a realistic 3D fractal-generated Christmas tree. The best I could find is the Adobe Stock image below.

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Image by [Tupungato](https://stock.adobe.com/ee/images/abstract-fractal-background-christmas-tree-shape-3d/5462278).)</sup>

---

I would especially be interested in sufficient details that I could recreate its generation in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example from Code Project:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3412/%2FArticles%2F3412%2FCreate-a-Fractal-Christmas-Tree

and many more from Code Golf:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15860/make-a-scalable-christmas-tree

Comment: The rotating helical [Mathematica tree by Silvia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16428) is impressive!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I agree. And the TeX version is also impressive.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a simple generation of the tree which is in python [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15869/67367). Also you can use Barnsley fern generation technique to recreate the Christmass tree. I mean using the Barnsley fern as a leaf of the tree and multiplying some random rotation matrix in the result of the generated leaf to create a tree. Find more details about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern).

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with Barnsley's Interated Function Systems, but my experience is that it is not easy to produce a particular desired result. I don't doubt it can be achieved via IFS's.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke my pleasure. Yes, I agree with you in "it is not easy to produce a particular desired result."